# How do Joins & Relates in layer file and Layer Properties work?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, attribute-joins, arcgis-10.5, layer-file

I'm using ArcMap 10.5. I set up symbology for a feature class based on joined attributes from a table in the same file geodatabase. I want to be able to apply the same set-up in different geodatabases (where all of the feature classes, attribute fields etc are exactly the same, it's just e.g. from a different date to the original one), that are kept on different servers accessed by different people.

I've saved a layer file with the symbology. If I right click on the layer file in ArcCatalog, I can easily change the data source to a different geodatabase and the data displays okay on my PC. However, when I look at the Joins & Relates tab in the Layer Properties, the joined table location is still the original location. This means that while the data displays okay for me, for anyone else who doesn't have access to the same server as me, the join will not work and the symbology won't display.

Does anyone know a way around this?

I can't find any guidance from Esri about how a Join in a Layer File works, and it's all a bit confusing. Ideally changing the layer source would change the join location source too. Basically I'm trying to make the process of applying symbology as simple as possible for our users.

Is there any way to (easily, for non-expert users) apply join settings and symbology at the same time?

Comment: A layer file may not be the way to go, you may want to look into representations, that stores the symbology in the FC itself and the geodatabase.  If the symbology is based on a joined table in a geodatabase a table view may also be the most appropriate approach.